# Random number after the executation in C++

Tags: c++

Everything works like i wanted it to be but the only thing is that when i execute this file it generate some random number at the end of the line which i think is not normal and i know that something is wrong with this code, could anyone look into this code and tell me what is wrong

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void message();
int choose1(char);
int choose2(char);
int choose3(char);

int main()
{
    message();
    int inputA, inputB, inputC;
    cout<<"A little girl kicks a soccer ball. It goes 10 feet and comes back to her. How is this possible?"<<endl;
    cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Because the ball has air in it. "<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Because the ball went up. "<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Because of the gravity."<<endl;
    cin>>inputA;
    cout<<choose1(inputA)<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    system("cls");

    cout<<"How can a man go eight days without sleep?"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Because he is death. "<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Because he slept at night. "<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Because he is not born yet. "<<endl;
    cin>>inputB;
    cout<<choose2(inputB)<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    system("cls");

    cout<<"What can you never eat for breakfast??"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Breakfast. "<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Dinner. "<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Lunch. "<<endl;
    cin>>inputC;
    cout<<choose3(inputC)<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    system("cls");

    cout<<"\n\n\n\nThank you for playing this simple game K,Thsuyipa Yimchunger\n\n\n\n"<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void message(){
    system("color a");
    cout<<"===================================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"===================================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"Hi welcome to this simple math book"<<endl;
    cout<<"here we will ask you some simple question and"<<endl;
    cout<<"all you have to do is just press the number which \nyou think is the right answer"<<endl;
    cout<<"===================================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"===================================================="<<endl;
    cout<<"===================================================="<<endl;
}

int choose1(char input){    
    switch(input){
        case 1:
            cout<<"The answer is wrong.... Better luck next time"<<endl;
        break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"The answer is wrong.... Better luck next time"<<endl;
        break;
        case 3:
            cout<<"The answer is RIGHT.... Because she kick the ball and gravity pull it down ;) "<<endl;
        break;
        default:
            cout<<"You've entered a wrong digit"<<endl;
            return 1; //Same thing with a boolean. If it doesn't have a matching case, return 1 to note that is was a failure.
    }
}

int choose2(char input){    
    switch(input){
        case 1:
            cout<<"The answer is wrong.... Better luck next time"<<endl;
        break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"The answer is RIGHT.... Because he slept during the night time ;)"<<endl;
        break;
        case 3:
            cout<<"The answer is wrong.... Better luck next time "<<endl;
        break;
        default:
            cout<<"You've entered a wrong digit"<<endl;
            return 1; //Same thing with a boolean. If it doesn't have a matching case, return 1 to note that is was a failure.
    }
}

int choose3(char input){    
    switch(input){
        case 1:
            cout<<"The answer is wrong.... Better luck next time"<<endl;
        break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"The answer is RIGHT.... ;) "<<endl;
        break;
        case 3:
            cout<<"The answer is wrong.... Better luck next time"<<endl;
        break;
        default:
            cout<<"You've entered a wrong digit"<<endl;
            return 1; //Same thing with a boolean. If it doesn't have a matching case, return 1 to note that is was a failure.
    }
}
```

Comment: The line? Which line? There's a *lot* of lines here and I bet 99% of them have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: the random number here is the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/nnFhMaE.png

Comment: Note where the `return` statement is in your choose functions. This be illegal code. A function with a non-`void` return type must return a value on ALL paths.

Comment: how can i fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `choose1` function does not always return a value, so that means you have *undefined behaviour* and you're getting garbage results.

Any function of the form `int f()` *must* `return` an integer value. Your `switch` statement side-steps the only `return` in the function in all but the default case.

You may have a more aggressive compiler warning that can alert you to this situation, so if you're making mistakes like this there's no shame in turning on a lot of those so these are made more obvious and you don't waste your time debugging.

The basic fix is this:

```
int choose1(char input){    
    switch(input){
        case 1:
            cout<<"The answer is wrong.... Better luck next time"<<endl;
            return 1;
        case 2:
            cout<<"The answer is wrong.... Better luck next time"<<endl;
            return 1;
        case 3:
            cout<<"The answer is RIGHT.... Because she kick the ball and gravity pull it down ;) "<<endl;
            return 0;
        default:
            cout<<"You've entered a wrong digit"<<endl;
            return 1; //Same thing with a boolean. If it doesn't have a matching case, return 1 to note that is was a failure.
    }
}
```

Using `int` to represent what's actually a `bool` is problematic, as is a lot of the duplication here. When approaching a problem like this try and think in terms of *data* first, then how to display it second. For example, define a `std::vector` containing a simple `struct` that defines a question, possible answers, and the correct answer. This minimizes code duplication since you can write one function that displays one of these, asks for input, and validates the answer without having to be copy-pasted over and over.

Comment: Sir i am new in c++ and i am just started learning this programming language so if you could pin point and paste the correct code i would greatly appreciate it

Comment: I've added some more clarification here, but this is not a substitute for a good C++ introduction book and some time reading up on the fundamentals. C++ is a ruthlessly indifferent language, it will do *exactly* what you ask of it regardless of consequences, so be very careful when writing code to check that you're doing it correctly even if it means consulting your reference material frequently. Like a chainsaw it's very powerful, but also unsafe if you're not paying close attention to how you're using it.

Comment: Thank you Sir i have learn a lot from your comment and your answer posted above. I will try to minimizes my code so that i don't have to copy paste ever question everytime. Thank you so much tadman have a great day.....